# Helm remote connection on Kubernetes server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to move my helm (`/usr/local/bin/helm`) to another server, and I can't work out how to helm to connect to remote tiller or a remote Kubernetes server.

Helm is running locallyy on the server B (k8s). I want it to run server A, to be able to connect to the server B to execute the YAML files.

Comment: Can you clear you query? What are your server A and B?

Answer (score 6):

IIRC Helm should act against whichever cluster is set as your current context for `kubectl` on server A.

Set up kubectl on your server. Use `kubectl config use-context` to target the cluster and helm should follow.

You'll probably want to do `helm init --client-only` on the server to initialize helm without reinstalling tiller.

> NOTE: This only applies to Helm 2. Tiller has been removed in Helm 3.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for Helm really skim over this and don't do a good job of explaining but after closer inspection:

> You should also have a local configured copy of `kubectl`.

https://helm.sh/docs/intro/quickstart/

> Helm will figure out where to install Tiller by reading your
> Kubernetes configuration file (usually `$HOME/.kube/config`). This is
> the same file that `kubectl` uses.

Also, if you have a newer version of Helm there's no need to install Tiller, it's been removed [as noted in the release notes](https://helm.sh/blog/helm-3-released/).

https://v2.helm.sh/docs/using_helm/

@switchboard.op is correct just adding this as an answer with some more ancillary information

Comment: `The docs for Helm really skim` is a very sad truth. Given the impact helm has on the industry, one can feel the technical debt building up in the pipelines of this world.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can use a `--kubeconfig` parameter just as you would with *kubectl*
You probally get a warning because this is not entirely production safe:
*"WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location: ./my-config.yml"*

A command like `helm --kubeconfig=./my-config.yml repo update` will use the connection from the yaml file to connect to the respected server noted there.

Kubectl looks at a couple of things for the connection and I found you can do the same for helm:

1. inline like the `--kubeconfig` param
2. $KUBECONFIG environment variable set to the value of the entire config
3. A file located at: *"~/.kube/config"*

Paths for specific Helm configs are:

| Operating System | Cache Path | Configuration Path | Data Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Linux | $HOME/.cache/helm | $HOME/.config/helm | $HOME/.local/share/helm |
| macOS | $HOME/Library/Caches/helm | $HOME/Library/Preferences/helm | $HOME/Library/helm |
| Windows | %TEMP%\helm | %APPDATA%\helm | %APPDATA%\helm |

Using `helm get -h` helps a lot in finding out about options, more than https://helm.sh/docs/intro/quickstart/#reading-the-help-text

`--kubeconfig` command is listed here as an example: https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_all/